# Countdown timer in PrimeFaces confirmDialog

Tags: javascript, primefaces, dialog, countdowntimer

In my web application I have a idle monitor which is triggered if a user is idle for 5 minutes. It will open a confirm dialog which will wait for 2 minutes; after that it will redirect to login page.

Requirement: I want to show a countdown timer with the time remaining before the user will be redirected to the login page.

baseTemplate.xhtml:

```
<h:form>

    <p:idleMonitor timeout="#{idleMonitorView.timeoutVal}"
        onidle="startTimer()" />

    <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
        message="You have been idle, Please click ok to remain logged in"
        header="Are you there?" severity="alert" widgetVar="idleDialog">                 
        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Ok" oncomplete="extendSession()" />

    </p:confirmDialog>

    <p:remoteCommand name="terminateIdleSession" actionListener="#{idleMonitorView.onIdle}" out="count" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var extend_session = 0;
        function startTimer() {

            extend_session = 0;
            setTimeout("timeout()", 120000);
            PF('idleDialog').show();
        }

        function timeout() {
            if (extend_session == 0) {
                terminateIdleSession();
            }
        }

        function extendSession() {
            extend_session = 1;
            PF('idleDialog').hide();
        }
    </script>
</h:form>
```

Problem: I don't know that how to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a JavaScript interval which updates a timer every second (or any other interval you need). You can update your timer using a bit of jQuery. I would recommend to add a span to the dialog message which you can use as a timer:

```js
$("#myForm\\:confirmDialog .ui-confirm-dialog-message").append("<span id=logoffTimeout/>");
```

You should replace `myForm` with the ID you've used on your form here.

When the dialog is shown, calculate the time your logoff timer will expire and store it for example in `window.logoffTime`. Now you can use the following function to update the timer:

```js
function updateTimer(){
  var seconds = Math.ceil((window.logoffTime - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
  $("#logoffTimeout").html(seconds);
}
```

On your buttons and remote command I would suggest to use `process="@this"`. See also: [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

What you should know is when you start a timeout in JavaScript, an ID is returned. You can use that ID to clear your timeout.

I ended up with this XHTML:

```html
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
                 message="Please click Ok before the timer runs out: "
                 header="Are you there?"
                 severity="alert"
                 closable="false"
                 widgetVar="idleDialog">
  <p:commandButton id="confirm"
                   value="Ok"
                   process="@this"
                   onclick="clearTimeout(window.logoffTimeoutId); PF('idleDialog').hide();"/>
</p:confirmDialog>

<p:remoteCommand name="terminateIdleSession"
                 actionListener="#{idleMonitorView.onIdle}"
                 process="@this"
                 out="count"/>

<p:idleMonitor timeout="#{5 * 60 * 1000}"
               onidle="startTimer()"/>
```

And this JavaScript:

```js
function startTimer() {
  clearTimeout(window.logoffUpdaterId);
  PF('idleDialog').show();
  // Set timeout to 2 minutes
  var timeout = 2 * 60 * 1000;
  // Calculate when the time runs out
  window.logoffTime = new Date().getTime() + timeout;
  // Start timer which calls remote command
  window.logoffTimeoutId = setTimeout(terminateIdleSession, timeout);
  // Update timer every second
  window.logoffUpdaterId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
  // Update timer now
  updateTimer();
}

// Update the timer
function updateTimer() {
  var seconds = Math.ceil((window.logoffTime - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
  $("#logoffTimeout").html(seconds);
}

// Create span to contain the timer
$(function(){
  $("#myForm\\:confirmDialog .ui-confirm-dialog-message").append("<span id=logoffTimeout/>");
});
```

I've noted that you are using your JavaScript embedded in your XHTML. In that case add `CDATA` to prevent running into XML errors:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...
//]]>
</script>
```

I would suggest to load your script from a file / resource which will give you the benefit of caching.

### 2024 update

PrimeFaces Extensions now has a component to deal with session expiry.

```html
<pe:session onexpire="PF('sessionDialog').show()"
            onexpired="PF('sessionDialog').hide();PF('sessionExpiredDialog').show()"
            reactionPeriod="60"/>

<p:dialog widgetVar="sessionDialog" header="Session Warning">
    <p>Your session is about to expire.</p>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Keep my session alive." onsuccess="PF('sessionDialog').hide()"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog widgetVar="sessionExpiredDialog" header="Session Expired">
    <p>Your session has expired.</p>
</p:dialog>
```

See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/session/basic.jsf

Comment: I am getting  this Error "Open quote is expected for attribute "id" associated with an  element type  "span". ". And Dialog box is also not coming up.But when i removed the function 'Create span to contain the timer' then dialog box come up without timer.

Comment: @Narendra I've updated the answer. Please add CDATA to your script.

Comment: I have one issue that,after click on Ok button, timeout is not being reset. to 5 minute.Explanation: Suppose i am idle for 5 minute,then Dialog box is coming up to wait for 2 minute,and if i click on OK Button after 50 seconds the Dialog Box is being Hide but after (120-50=70) seconds it's automatic redirecting to login Page ( Without any confirmation dialog).It seems it's not resetting timeoutVal to 5 minute.It's keep timeoutVal=2 minute

Comment: My bad. `logoffTimeoutId` should have been cleared. See update.

Comment: Now it's perfect.

Comment: Maybe we should add this to `p:idleMonitor` and create a pull request...

Comment: Now I am getting one problem if multiple Browser Tabs are open and one page is active  and other are not still user is going to be logged out.In my application session is managed by Spring.

Comment: in your `onIdle` you could check the http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime-- to detect activity in different tabs / windows.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Jasper de Vries on 2017-04-29T18:13 is fantastic, elegant and works great, I would just like to add that since PF version 8 the "p:idleMonitor" component has the "multiWindowSupport" parameter which when configured in true, the last accessed state will be shared between all browser windows for the same servlet context.

```xml
<p:idleMonitor timeout="#{5 * 60 * 1000}"
               onidle="startTimer()"
               multiWindowSupport="true"
/>
```

HappyCoding;

Comment: You might want to check out https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/session/basic.jsf

Comment: Thank you very much, excellent complement.